# ¿Como guardar una imagen en la BD microsft sql server desde NetFramework 4.7.2 api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Ayuda a poder obtener el byte[] o el cuerpo y poder ingresar mi imagen enviada a una BD , soy nuevo en eso y estoy queriendo realizar una api para poder comunicarme desde xamarin,
ya puedo guardar en carpeta la imagen pero no en la BD y necesito guardarla en ambas partes, ya lo he probado en winform o webform pero como se usa un fileupload aqui no se como hacer, mi BD tiene varbanary(max) la parte de la columna imagen.

Este es mi codigo de xamarin el cual esta consumiendo la api que tiene.

```
private async void prueba_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            // Toast.MakeText(this, "Upload not supported on this device", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
        {
            PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Full,
            CompressionQuality = 40,


        });

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new StreamContent(file.GetStream()),
            "\"file\"",$"\"{ file.Path}\"");
      
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "http://10.x.x.x/api/api/Files/Upload";
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);


        if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Datos", "Se actualizo correctamente la información", "OK");

        }

        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Datos", "No se realizo el insert", "OK");



        }



    }
}
```

Esta es mi API por la cual esto trabajando en net fremework 4.7, esta es una clase, para poder llamar al post, soy nuevo en esta combinación .

```
 [Route("api/Files/Upload")]



public async Task<string> Post()

{


        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count>0)
            {
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {

         
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
                    var guid    =Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" +guid + fileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                  
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////
                    //var content = postedFile;


                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insertar_Imagen", Conexion.conec);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagen", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = //Aqui Quiero tener el dato u otra forma;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@descripcion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName;



                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



                    return "/Uploads/" + fileName;
                }
              
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
         return exception.Message;
        }
        return "No files";
    }
```

Comment: Y... cuál es el problema? Te tira un error? Cómo sugieres que te ayudemos?

Comment: hola  gracias por comentar no ingresa a la BD el byte o la imagen adecuada me guarda un numero 0x86 nada mas , me gustaría que me ayudaran en poder ingresar la imagen en la BD no importa si necesito realizar otra forma de codificación la idea es ingresar la imagen en la BD, porque he googleado y he usado memorystream y sigue guardando pocos byte's o lo estoy haciendo mal estoy confundido en esa parte

Comment: Qué versión de .net estás utilizando? NetFramework (~4.7), netCore(2.1,3), .Net5?

Comment: La version de .NET es la NetFramework 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Me voy a concentrar en tu código, sobre todo en el comentario

> `cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagen", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = //Aqui Quiero tener el dato u otra forma;`

Puesto que lo que te falta, al parecer, es la conversión de la imagen a un arreglo de bytes, que es lo que se guarda, generalmente, en la base de datos. Mucha gente dice que no es buena práctica guardar imágenes en la BD, que sólo se debe guardar la ruta, y lo comparto, sin embargo, si quieres hacerlo, no seré yo quien te detenga.

En .Net, `HttpContext.Request.Files` es un `HttpFileCollectionBase`, una colección de `HttpPostedFileBase`, y cada uno de ellos tiene una propiedad llamada `InputStream`, que puede ser copiado a un `Stream` temporal y luego ser convertido a un arreglo de bytes. Puedes mover esta conversión a un método aparte:

```
private byte[] ConvertToByteArray(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (var streamTemporal = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(streamTemporal);
                return streamTemporal.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return new byte[] { };
    }
```

Y lo puedes llamar desde el controlador.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagen", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = ConvertToByteArray(archivo);
```

Eso debería ser suficiente para convertir el archivo a un formato que el procedimiento almacenado acepte.

Comment: Disculpa la ignorancia Ariel pero esta parte cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagen", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = ConvertToByteArray(archivo);  he puesto las variables del archivo y me da error , puedes explicarme por favor la parte que variable poner al llamar el metodo ConvertToByteArray(archivo);    en base a  mi ejemplo o debo de declarar antes la variable?

Comment: Sólo copiaste y pegaste el código? Nada más? En qué tecnología, exactamente, estás trabajando: WebApi2, MVC5, WebForms, WinForms? Cómo le mandas los archivos al controlador? Por qué estás iterando sobre `strings`? Por qué no estás trabajando directamente con el archivo mismo y sólo con la ruta?

Comment: trabajo con xamarin consumiendo una api, Trabajo con Api web .net framework no MVC , necesito guardar la imagen en la BD por ahora solo lo estoy guardando en una carpeta, copie el codigo y realice las pruebas siguiente: al cambiar la variable archivo al llamar el metodo puse httqrequest o file pero con ninguna me aceptaba por el tipo de variable, porque la varriable HttpPostedFileBase file en el metodo  no  se como enviarle una variable adecuada para probar tu codigo modificare la pregunta agregando lo de xamarin para ver si me comprendes

Comment: Entonces, no tienes acceso a la imagen? Si no tienes la imagen, cómo vas a guardarla en la base de datos?

Comment: Hola, si tengo acceso a la imagen la guardo en una carpeta como te comentaba , modifique la pregunta para ver si me puedes ayudar , ya que tu area del codigo al llamar al metodo desconozco cual variable mandar, por eso modifique mi pregunta para que le des una ojeada y me ayudes